# Why Swing Components have .getParent() method, Is it violated Object Oriented Principles?

Tags: java, swing, oop, software-design, object-oriented-analysis

I am working on Object Oriented Design Principles and Heuristics. 
In the remarkable book named Object-Oriented Design Heuristics By Arthur J. Riel (1996) I see this heuristic:

**Heuristic 4.13**: A class must know what it contains, but it should never know who contains it.
Based on J.Reil, The main reason is reusability.

But in Swing Structure, we can access directly to the reference of Parent object.

for example: `label.getParent()`

So my question is: 
Why swing components have .getParent() method? 
Which Object Oriented **Priciples** or **Heuristics** are behid of existing this method?

Comment: It's unclear that this heuristic is commonly agreed upon.

Comment: It is a cyclic dependency between the parent and the child. It can be a code smell too. We should use something like "bridge" object to access parent.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "dependency".  If you want to navigate from the child to the parent, you're going to need an edge somewhere.  You can avoid the type dependency by using a "component" interface or similar.

Comment: So, would a double linked list also be a bad idea?

Comment: No, it's just a structural tools, if you want to use it in any case, you should follow PRINCIPLES of the context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things here: no rules are cast in stone in software engineering. It is always about balancing different aspects that are somehow competitive.

Then: the main purpose of UI components is (surprise) to be used in UIs. And typically any UI element belongs to exactly one parent. You can't have the same table showing up in two windows (maybe the same data, but not the UI table objects!). And from there: getting to the parent of a UI component is something that you need all the time. UI elements are always owned - and it is much more convenient when you can go up and down easily.

Long story short: I think you are looking at a very special case here - where it simply makes a lot of sense to deviate from a rule written in some book.

Comment: thanks a lot, I understand what you mean. I could not explain this violation in my class. However I persist the truth of this heuristic in any other systems (except UI Degin)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I haven't read the book in question, so I can only speculate on what the author meant.

But my surmise would be that what is intended here is that the class should not *change its behavior* based on the *type* of the class that contains it. So, a `Button` must not behave differently when it's in a `ScrollPane` than it does if it is in a `JPanel` or a `JFrame`.

But the *hierarchy* of components in the UI is part of their responsibilities. They are in a tree structure, and so they not only maintain links to one another, but they have accessors to allow client code to navigate that structure. Now, you could have a structure where only the parents had links to the children, and not vice versa, just as you could have a singly-linked list. But to have a doubly-linked list, where each node has a pointer, not only the the node after it, but also a pointer back to the node before it, is not a violation of object-oriented principles, and neither is it a violation to have a doubly-linked tree structure where the child nodes also have pointers that allow navigating *up* the tree, from children to parents.

We must ask ourselves, *how* would knowing who contains it impair reusability? Why would knowing that make the class less reusable? Now, if it changed its behavior based on who contained it, that would do it. You could not just take the class and use it somewhere else, because it might not do what you expect it to do. But merely maintaining the links doesn't harm reusability.

(I would note that, if you're going to add and remove components from the hierarchy, there has to be some care taken in their API so that when you tell one of them you're severing the link, both of them can update their state. But that can be handled as part of the API design. As long as that was done up front in the first version so that it's part of the contract of all classes that are written to be part of that component hierarchy, it would not pose a problem.)